# Is there any full aspect-oriented programming language?

Tags: oop, programming-languages, aop

When I say "full" I mean a language that's not an extension to some already existent language like Java or C++. When OOP started it begun with extensions for procedural languages like C and Pascal. Is there any Aspect-Oriented programming language "by itself"?

Comment: is this a curiosity type question or are you trying to solve a particular problem ?

Comment: Also - the purpose of aspects is to add functionality to existing code - so whats the point of having an AOP language? (Unless you think about how to express aspects and pointcuts)

Comment: Curiosity, and yes i pretend to express aspects and pointcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No

But there are languages that contain constructs that mimic aspects, for example Haskel which contains the possibility to add advices or Smalltalk because of its message approach. You could also look at Eifel with its contract oriented approach - that could be compared to applying aspects to functions.

But a pure AOP language, I would say no.

Edit: And sure enough, someone found an AOP language ;)

Comment: I agree that if the motivation is to perform AOP like functions smalltalk, haskel or ruby do the job so much better than Java or C#.

Comment: The hardest thing to prove, is to prove something doesn't exist (especially if it logically it can)

Comment: Could you add a link to a description of the Haskell advice feature? "Advice" is not a search-friendly name ...

Comment: Maybe I was too quick there, I ment that you could use monads to archive the AOP effect.

Comment: It looks like there's no such thing yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is as usual "Lisp". It has after and before methods in the ANSI Lisp Definition and you can do a lot of the AOP stuff with macros.